# VSCode Pylance changed text color

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I just installed Pylance on VisualStudioCode, my theme is OneDarkPro.

I can manually set the text color with editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations in settings.json but I wonder if there is a way to simply keep my previous text color.

This is how my code looked like before installing Pylance:

[image]

This is how it looks like now:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is caused by "[Editor semantic highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_editor-semantic-highlighting)". Please add the following settings to the settings file "settings.json" to turn off semantic highlighting:

```
"[python]": {
        "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false,
    },
```

OneDarkPro and Pylance:

[image]

Reference: [Semantic highlighting colors every variable with same color](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/323).